# Why do I get '$(...).autocomplete is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, jsp, firefox, autocomplete

I'm trying to make my autocomplete work but Firebug is showing me this error:

> TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function.

I don't know why it's not working since I've imported all the right files to make my autocomplete work.
Here are the libraries I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"/>" ></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"/>" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And here's the line I use for my autocomplete:

```
<script>
$("#services_autocomplete").autocomplete("getcountries.jsp");
</script>
```

Comment: Try `$(function(){   $("#services_autocomplete").autocomplete("getcountries.jsp");   })`

Comment: i think you did not load your scripts properly

Comment: Why are you loading `jquery.js` _and_ `jquery.min.js` 1.3.2? 1.3.2 is _reeeally_ old btw.

Comment: Thanks @Kenney but it's not working :( - And J.Kovacevic my scripts are loaded properly because firebug recognizes them and is not throwing me any exception. Andy Am I supposed to load only one of them ? Sorry I just wanted to be sure i've all the files I need

Comment: move your code to document ready. It is likely order of loading: $(function(){ $("#services_autocomplete").autocomplete("getcountries.jsp"); });

Comment: Remove the last jquery include, it may 'reset' the jquery that knows about jquery-ui and jquery.autocomplete.

Comment: Thank you @Kenney. It works !! Well my autocomplete still does not work but I don't have this error anymore ! Thank you

Comment: You should mention in your question what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Load jquery only once, and do it as the first one. 
That will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you only include *one* jQuery version. The one from the Google API is unnecessary and also totally outdated.

Then check if jQuery, jQuery UI and your autocomplete plugin are really loaded. I.e. have a look within the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) and see if they are listed in black (and not in red). Or you can also check the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) and see if 'jquery.js', 'jquery-ui.min.js' and 'jquery.autocomplete.js' are listed within its Script Location Menu.

If they are red/not there, the paths to your files are wrong.

If all files are included correctly, you still have to put your call to the `autocomplete()` function into a `$()` to ensure that it's executed once the page is completely loaded:

```
$(function(){
  $("#services_autocomplete").autocomplete("getcountries.jsp");
});
```

See the [documentation for the `.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function for more info on that.